# Strange result when nesting query of two different collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a need to check two separate collections in Mongo to see if a phone number exists.

I first created a global variable called 'ownerId'

I then look in one collection call 'Profile'. If the email value I pass exists in the 'emails' array of a document in that collection, I fill the 'ownerId' variable I created with a value in that document called 'owner_id'.

I then look in another collection called 'User', which has a single email field. If the email value I pass exists in a document in that collection, I fill the 'ownerId' variable I created with the '_id' of that document.

I have my queries nested in a couple 'then()' statements.

Here is my code:

```
            Profile.findOne({'emails.email_address':req.body.invited_email}, function(err, result){

                if(result)
                    ownerId = result.owner_id;

            }).then(function(){
                User.findOne({'email':req.body.invited_email}, function(err, result2){

                    if(ownerId !== null)
                        ownerId = result2._id;
                })
            }).then(function(){

              console.log(' --------------- THIS IS AN EXISTING EMAIL OWNER ID: ' + ownerId);

            })
```

The result is not as I expect.

If the 'Profile' query is true and finds a match, then it will console log the ownerId with a value.

If the second 'User' query is true, but there is not match for the 'Profile' it will console log 'null'. I expect it to console log the _id value of the User result.

Can anyone see the error in my logic?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mix callbacks and promises. I would recommend using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) for this. It makes asynchronous code look synchronous. For example:

```
let owner_id;

try {
  let profile = await Profile.findOne({ 'emails.email_address': req.body.invited_email });
  let user = await User.findOne({ 'email': req.body.invited_email }):

  if (profile) {
    owner_id = profile.owner_id;
  } else if (user) {
    owner_id = user.owner_id;
  } else {
    console.log('no owner id found');
  }
} catch(err) {
   console.log(err);
}
```

The code is wrapped in try/catch to handle errors, just like the `catch()` method for ordinary promises. The functions using `await` needs the [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) keyword.

`await` is used to wait for promises to finish. No callbacks are needed. You can see the code looks like ordinary synchronous code.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mika, but I get the following console error:                       let profile = await Profile.findOne({ 'emails.email_address': req.body.invited_email });
                                          ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: In Mongoose 4.x isn't a .then() function meant to handle promises so you don't need any extra work to use mongoose with async/await?

Comment: Is it complaining about the await? Hard to see where the arrows are pointing when the code is pasted into the comment. You need version 7.6 or later of node for async/await. You should upgrade to the latest version if you can. Both then and async/await uses promises, await just makes it easier.

Comment: Ah. I'm using an earlier version of Node 6.9.2. The arrows are under 'Profile' after 'await'. I'll see if upgrading works.

Comment: If you want to try with your original code you can try adding `return` in front of `User.findOne()`. Can't promise you that it works, but it might.